# How to correctly add a second child to <mark> HTML element in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm having the following error in React:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import './Mark.css'
import { forEach } from "lodash";

export interface MarkProps {
  key: string
  content: string
  start: number
  end: number
  tag: string
  colors?: Array<string>
  onClick: (any: any) => any
}


export default function Mark(props: MarkProps) {
  function printProps() {
    console.log("The props")
    console.log(props)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    printProps()
  }, [])

  return (
    <mark
      style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', display: 'inline-grid', rowGap: '0', padding: '0 4px' }}
      data-start={props.start}
      data-end={props.end}
      onClick={() => props.onClick({ start: props.start, end: props.end })}

    >
      {
        props.content && (
          <span style={{ textDecoration: 'underline', textDecorationColor: '#84d2ff' }}>{props.content}</span>
        )
      }
      {
        props.colors?.map((col: string) => {
          console.log(col); <span className='dot' style={{ backgroundColor: col }}></span>
        })
      }

    </mark>
  )
}
```

Error comes from trying to display a span dot for each of the colors within `props.colors`.

The only thing that I've tried that doesn't display an error is:

```
      {
        props.colors?.map((col: string) => {
          console.log(col); <span className='dot' style={{ backgroundColor: col }}></span>
        }) && <></>
      }
```

However, in this way nothing gets displayed.

What's the correct way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Text should not be presented as images.

Comment: [Sanay Varghese's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74632165/17670742) seems to solve your problem, but I am very interested in understanding why the missing return in your `map()` function generated this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a return in map function

```
  {props.colors?.map((col: string, index) => {
    return (
      <span
        className="dot"
        style={{ backgroundColor: col, width: "10px", height: "10px" }}
        key={index}
      ></span>
    );
  })}
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: This appears to have resolved it in my testing, further explanation would be useful though. Why did this generate the single child error?

Comment: This error is thrown because you are using **TypeScript**. 

If you are using map without returning nothing it return unknown. According to Typescript `<mark>` element is a `React.ReactNode` which includes `ReactFragment` which is recursively implemented as `Iterable<ReactNode>`. That's why a `ReactNode` can be an array of `ReactNodes`. However, unknown means the type is not defined as **Typescript is a strong typed Programming language**

Answer (score 0):

You have to return something from `{}`. See code comment for better understanding.

```
return (
    <mark
      style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', display: 'inline-grid', rowGap: '0', padding: '0 4px' }}
      data-start={props.start}
      data-end={props.end}
      onClick={() => props.onClick({ start: props.start, end: props.end })}

    >
      {
        props.content && (
          <span style={{ textDecoration: 'underline', textDecorationColor: '#84d2ff' }}>{props.content}</span>
        )
      }
      {
        props.colors?.map((col: string) => {
          console.log(col); 
            {/*  ---------> added return to next line */}
           return <span className='dot' style={{ backgroundColor: col }}></span> 
        })
      }

    </mark>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

`mark` is expecting one child (*This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child*). instead, you are providing two children.

You can solve this to wrap the children into a `Fragment`, [read more here](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Also, your map is not returning anything yet. This can be fixed by actually returning the `span`

```
return (
    <mark
      style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)', display: 'inline-grid', rowGap: '0', padding: '0 4px' }}
      data-start={props.start}
      data-end={props.end}
      onClick={() => props.onClick({ start: props.start, end: props.end })}

    >
    <React.Fragment>
      {
        props.content && (
          <span style={{ textDecoration: 'underline', textDecorationColor: '#84d2ff' }}>{props.content}</span>
        )
      }
      {
        props.colors?.map((col: string) => {
          console.log(col);
          return <span className='dot' style={{ backgroundColor: col }}></span>
        })
      }
     </React.Fragment>
    </mark>
  )
```